# Applying an impulse to an SKSprite in a random direction

Tags: sprite-kit

I have a ball that I would like to apply an impulse to. This I know how to do. What I don't know how to do is randomize the direction of the ball. How would this be done.

Comment: How do you apply the impulse to your sprites now? Will two random float numbers for `dx` and `dy` be enough in your case?

Comment: @WangYudong Thank you so much for responding! Yes two random float numbers should be enough. As I am pretty new to the Swift Programming Language I don't really know how to do this. Do you? Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The way to generate random float:

```
func randomFloatBetween(lower: CGFloat, upper: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UINT32_MAX) * (upper - lower) + lower
}
```

Use it to make your random `CGVector`.